# How to add right button in the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a question to add a right button in navigation bar..

I have two views: View A and View B

I add a navigation bar to view A, after I used `self.navigationController!.pushViewController` to show view B.

That show a back button in the left of navigation bar of view B automatic, it is good. but now I want to add a button in the right of navigation bar of view B.. 
I have tried some answers, but it doesn't work...
I have tried answers likes :
1) https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-bar-button-to-a-navigation-bar
2)http://blog.apoorvmote.com/add-multiple-bar-button-item-navigation-bar/?lang=fr

Could you help me, thank you !

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Swift version of Vahan Babayan's answer, as you seem to use this language, is:

```
let rightButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(
      title: "Title", 
      style: .Done, 
      target: self, 
      action: "rightButtonAction:"
)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonItem
```

The following method will be called on self:

```
func rightButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
```

Note that all this **can be set graphically using a Storyboard**, by dragging a Bar Button Item to your Navigation Item and right-clicking to set a target-action.

---

A small update since Swift 3 and 4 are out: the compiler can now check selector names, preventing typos when setting up target-action programatically. So one should really use:

```
let rightButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(
      title: "Title", 
      style: .Done, 
      target: self, 
      action: #selector(rightButtonAction(sender:))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have fund the answer to ` let rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Send", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "send:")
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(rightBtn, animated: true)` I know I can use XIB to do that, but I do not why the position of the right button is not the same with by XIB, so I use code to do this

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following code to your B controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                                    target:self 
                                                                    action:@selector(rightButtonAction:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Right Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(rightBtnClick)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;
}

-(void)rightBtnClick{
    // code for right Button

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in viewDidLoad Method

```
UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Flip"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(flipView:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
```

This adds a button to the right hand side with the title Flip, which calls the method:

```
-(IBAction)flipView
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift code to add a navigation bar button item:

**Method 1** (When you wanna use bar button system item)

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
```

**Method 2** (When you wanna give your own title to button)

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
```

From iOS 5 onwards, it allows you to add more than 1 button on either side of a navigation bar. Something like this:

```
let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
let display = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Display", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(playTapped))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [add, display]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code for **Swift UI** :

```
 .navigationBarItems(
   leading:
     HStack {
       Button("About") {
         print("About tapped!")
       }
       Button("Call") {
         print("Call tapped!")
       }
     },
                                    
   trailing:
     HStack {
       Button("Settings") {
         print("Settings tapped!")
       }
       Button("Contacts") {
         print("Contacts tapped!")
       }           
     }
  )
```