# Can i know what is the thing above the tab controller and how to create that?

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

https://cnet4.cbsistatic.com/img/mnkIa-L_cSwif5enQxFB0asQcxw=/fit-in/370x0/2016/08/03/edb0f835-70de-47fa-a8b3-55a09a14acb7/ios-10-music-app-4.jpg

I would like to create something like that above but i had no idea what is it? Can someone tell what thing is that and how can i create it ? Thanks.

**EDIT(SOLVED)**

1. I had solve this problem using this library https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController. For anyone who does not know how to create the music app like tab bar you can use the library above

Comment: When you solve your own question post it as an answer and accept it instead of editing your post.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

That's a navigation bar button. It can be created with [Interface Builder](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/04/14/adding-buttons-to-the-navigation-bar-with-storyboards/) [or code](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-bar-button-to-a-navigation-bar) [(stackoverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36694122/1166266).

Some [further reading from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar) about the `UINavigationController` class. It's a bit deeper than I think you want but it's full of other useful info about the whole design pattern and using it.